# Cura G-code Printer G-code settings vs. Extruder G-code settings

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

I am configuring my Cura G-code settings, and I'm not sure if the Printer G-code settings (printer tab of Machine Settings) should be the same as the Extruder G-code settings (extruder tab of Machine Settings). Does one set of settings override the other? Should they be different?

I'm using the following for Printer Start G-code:

```
M140 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ;Start heating bed
M104 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ;Start heating extruder
G28 ;home
G90 ;absolute positioning
G1 X-10 Y-10 F3000
G1 Z0 F1800
G92 E0
G1 E20 F200
G92 E0
```

Printer End G-code:

```
M104 S0 ;extruder heater off
M140 S0 ;heated bed heater off (if you have it)
G90 ;absolute positioning
G92 E0
G1 E-1 F300 ;retract the filament a bit before lifting the nozzle, to release some of the pressure
G28 X0 Y0
M84 ;steppers off
```

Answer (score 3):

If your printer has only one extruder, leave the Extruder G-Code empty. This setting is useful for multi-extruder printing (e.g. multicolor). The extruder G-Code runs each time you switch to and away from that extruder, and can be used for stuff such as retracting a filament when switching.